# Interpreting replicator dynamic for simplest population model

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology, evolutionary-game-theory

Suppose the simplest population model where we track the size $y$ of a population:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ry$$

for a positive constant $r$ and some $y$ such that $y(0) > 0$.

For this population model there is a corresponding "replicator dynamic" model defined by

$$x_0 := \frac{1}{1+y}$$

$$x_1 := \frac{y}{1+y}$$

These are supposed to model "frequencies" of different variants in a population,

QUESTION

except its not clear to me what the different variants here. There is only a single species here so of course it is 100% of its own population or 100% of all populations being modeled here, so I feel that I must be misunderstanding what the "frequencies" of the replicator dynamic are. Can someone clarify what $x_0$ and $x_1$ correspond to here? Thank you!

Comment: [Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)? Where did you encounter this model?

Comment: Hi @HansLundmark, it comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation#Relationships_to_other_equations . Basically $y$ models the size of some population where as $x_0$ and $x_1$ are the standard transformation from population models to the replicator dynamic from evolutionary game theory. The purpose of doing this is to study the evolutionary fitness for understanding if some population's strategy is evolutionarily stable or not. The interpretation of $x_0$ and $x_1$ usually given is that they are "frequencies" (i.e. proportions) but it's not clear what they correspond to in ESS.

Comment: I tried to make sense of https://homepage.univie.ac.at/josef.hofbauer/81na.pdf where the equivalent systems are compared, but it seems to be a rather mathematical manipulation, so it would be hard to think of a meaningful explanation of $x_i$. I don't think should be compared to the meaning of $x_i$ in "normal" replicator equations. Solving the replicator equation with these $x_0$ and $x_1$ will just give the same answer, in a different form (and they can be transformed back to $y$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, since you are dealing with a single population, you are modelling the evolution in time of the size of the population as a consequence of some process - for example, reproduction. There is no "frequency" involved, the size of the population (in the continuous limit) is a real positive number.

In the simplest possible model the population grows in proportion to its size (let me forget about the growth rate, setting $r=1$), giving the ODE
$$
\tag{1}
\dot{y} = y
$$

This is readily solved as $$y(t) = y_0e^t$$
and is clearly unfeasible in real applications, since it implies exponential growth ad-infinitum, so we need to introduce some process limiting the growth - for example, an environment with limited resources that enforces a carrying capacity.

The growth of a population in a setting with limited resources is a key environmental process. Examples include plants that grow with a certain mean flow of energy, water, and nutrients, or animals with a limited flow of food.  A simple model for this process is given by the [logistic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth): $\dot{x} = x(C-x)$, where $C$ is the carrying capacity of the environment; for simplicity let me set $C = 1$, so $$\tag{2}\dot{x} = x(1-x)$$ For small values of $x$, the population grows exponentially; as $x$ approaches carrying capacity, the limiting resources play a major role. This ODE is readily solved analytically and gives
$$
x(t) = \frac{x_0e^t}{x_0(e^t-1)+1}$$
Here is a trajectory for initial population of 0.1:
[image: Here is a trajectory for initial population of 0.1]

Now, to your question: the change of variable
$$x = \frac{y}{y+1}$$
turns $(1)$ into $(2)$ (check by chain rule).

The interpretation is the following: the Taylor expansion of $y/(y+1)$ around $0$ is clearly $0+y+\dots$, so for small population size $x$ behaves like $y$, i.e. reproduces the population size; while for big population size $y/(y+1) \to 1$, i.e. $x$ tends to the carrying capacity.

Equation $(2)$ can be seen as a 1-dimensional instance of the [replicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation) equation, but this is rather uninformative, since the replicator equation models the evolution in time of the *distribution* of types within a population with at least two types. Anyways if you think of a payoff function $f(x) = 1$, then $\bar{f}(x) = xf(x) = x$ and $(2)$ is precisely the 1-dimensional replicator equation:
$$\dot{x} = x(f(x) - \bar{f}(x)) = x(1-x)$$

Finally, the change of variable
$$z = \frac{1}{y+1}$$
leads to the ODE
$$\tag{3}\dot{z} = z(z-1)$$
I haven't encountered it and I haven't put much thought into it now, but it seems to model a damped decay process rather than a damped growth process.